# lsconf not returning result on AIX

Tags: aix

We are using `lsconf|grep -i "Machine Serial Number"` to get Machine's Serial information on AIX Operating System. But on some of the machines it is not returning any information, just blank result. What can possibly the reason that lsconf not giving any result and what should I use instead.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Compare the OS-versions `oslevel -r` Also run your command this way: `LC_ALL=C lsconf|grep -i "Machine Serial Number"`

Comment: The OS Version is AIX 6.1. On some of AIX 6.1 it is running just fine, but on others it is not.

Comment: consider an alternative, `lsattr -El sys0 -a systemid`

Comment: Do you know or have any idea that what can possibly the reason for this. For some instances, I've noted that lsconf returning 'NOTAVAILABLE' instead of real serial.